# AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.json Not Logging Free Disk Space

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

On our instance (i-568a3f14) running Windows Server 2012 Standard we are trying to log the free disk space in CloudWatch. I've put the file AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.json in the directory C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Settings

The contents of the .json file are as follows :

```
{
"IsEnabled": true,
"EngineConfiguration": {
    "PollInterval": "00:00:05",
    "Components": [
        {
        "Id": "PerformanceCounterDisk",
        "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.PerformanceCounterComponent.PerformanceCounterInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
        "Parameters": {
            "CategoryName": "LogicalDisk",
            "CounterName": "% Free Space",
            "InstanceName": "C:",
            "MetricName": "FreeDiskPercentage",
            "Unit": "Percent",
            "DimensionName": "InstanceId",
            "DimensionValue": "i-568a3f14"
    },
    {
            "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.CloudWatch.CloudWatchOutputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
            "Id": "CloudWatch",
            "Parameters": {
            "AccessKey": "",
            "NameSpace": "Windows/Default",
            "Region": "eu-west-1a",
            "SecretKey": ""
        }
  }
  }
    ],
    "Flows": {
        "Flows": 
        [
            "(PerformanceCounterDisk),CloudWatch"
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

I've restarted the Ec2ConfigService, but still, we aren't getting any data logged. What am I missing or what else should I try.